# Why can't I toggle <br> visibility with jQuery 1.7.2 in Google Chrome?

Tags: jquery

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Walkman/ZpF8F/
If I try to `.toggle()` `<br>` elements, they wont disappear, but with `.hide()` it works. Why ?

What is the difference between the two methods ?
Also If you hide them first, then `.toggle()` unhide them.

Comment: I don't see any problem on FF 14.0.1.

Comment: I see what you are talking about.  Chrome. Is it browser specific?  It is odd.  I tried it with a <br />.  Same thing.  Pretty sure <br></br> is not valid :)

Comment: +1 nhahtdh. If you change the jsfiddle to jQuery 1.8.0, it works in Chrome, FF, and IE

Comment: I tried with `<br>`. Now I tried with Safari too, and same there. It works with jQuery 1.8 !

Comment: @Walkman: Probably you should just switch to 1.8.0.

Comment: it may not be that easy, because my CMS system uses 1.7.2 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a bug ticket on jquery site for that may be this will clear your doubt

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11289

Comment: I was expecting exactly this kind of answer, thanks !
but obviously didn't know where or what to search exactly myself, because I would do it :)

Comment: actually in my case, it seems it doesn't add `display:none` property to the element, but the point is the same

Comment: Link broken, says can't find it

Answer (score 0):

**Toggle** will hide a tag with a content inside, here's an [exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/SZfVf/) while **hide** just hide the tag even without content inside.

For more details about the difference you can still check [the source code of jquery 1.8](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js)